# alternative to 'dd' which doesn't truncate the file

Tags: files, io-redirection, dd

Does anyone know an alternative for 'dd', which won't truncate the file, without using: `conv=notrunc`. Adding `conv=notrunc` isn't supported via busybox/toybox due to limited amount of space.

For instance, I'd like the equivalent of

```
dd bs=4 count=3 skip=2 seek=3 if=file.in of=file.out conv=notrunc
```

But that would work where `dd` doesn't support `conv=notrunc`.

Comment: What are you using `dd` for?

Comment: I want to write a specific amount of data from file A to file B (at given offset), without truncating the file (B). E.g - I want all the data that appears after the offset + written_size to remain unaffected.

Comment: `dd bs=12 count=1...` is more efficient: `3+0 records in
3+0 records out
12 bytes copied, 0.000326187 s, 36.8 kB/s`
vs `1+0 records in
1+0 records out
12 bytes copied, 0.0001706 s, 70.3 kB/s
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the standard `<>` `sh` redirection operator which opens the file in read+write mode *without truncation*.

```
cat < file.in 1<> file.out
```

To copy the content of `file.in` at the start of `file.out`.

If you need to seek in the input or output file, and assuming your `dd` still supports these directives:

```
dd bs=4 count=3 skip=2 seek=3 < file.in 1<> file.out
```

If you don't have `dd` at all, you can try `head -c`, assuming your version takes care of leaving the pointer in the file at the right place upon exit (which IIRC older versions of busybox were not doing).

For instance, the equivalent of the above would be:

```
{
  head -c 8 > /dev/null        # seek input fd to offset 8
  head -c 12 <&1 > /dev/null   # seek output fd to offset 12
  head -c 12                   # copy 12 bytes
} < file.in 1<> file.out
```